# Should symbol table contain declaration symbols?

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, symbol-table

I am sorry, maybe it is a little bit an abstract question. But it can help me to understand usage of symbol tables. Suppose, I want to implement simplified C# compiler and here is the piece of code I want to compile:

```cs
// Let simplified version of c# language does not contain access modifiers 
// (all by default public)
class Foo
{
     int Sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};
```

Here is simplified AST  of the code:

```
ClassNode (name:Foo)
└─╴FuncNode (name:Sum, type:(a:int,b:int)->int)
   └─╴OperatorNode (name:+, type:(int,int)->int)
      ├─╴ArgNode (name:a, type:int)  
      └─╴ArgNode (name:b, type:int)
```

In other words, we have `ClassNode` which declares class Foo. That `ClassNode` has one `FuncNode` which declares function `Sum`. `FuncNode` contains body, which in turn simple arithmetic expression.

Chain of symbol tables can be looked like:

```
(Global symbol table)
┌────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│SymName │Type      │Attr       │
├────────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│Foo     │class:Foo │ClassDecl  │
└────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
         \/

(Inner symbol table)
┌────────┬────────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│SymName │Type                │Attr              │
├────────┼────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│Sum     │func:(int,int)->int │InstanceFuncDecl  │
└────────┴────────────────────┴──────────────────┘
        \/

(Inner symbol table)
┌────────┬─────┬─────────┐
│SymName │Type │Attr     │
├────────┼─────┼─────────┤
│a       │Int  │Argument │
│b       │Int  │Argument │
└────────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

1. Should symbol table contain information about declarations of classes/functions or it should contain only information about local variables/fields etc.? I suppose that it should contain both, because such information can be used for generation calling recursive functions (instead of extracting type of function from the AST (it will require traversing the AST) we can fast extract it from symbol table?)
2. Or maybe it is enough just to use typed abstract syntax tree without usage of any symbol tables?
3. Should nodes of AST contain references to records of symbol tables? For example to avoid duplication of information about types?
4. Maybe my chain of symbol tables are wrong? I guess that each class/func declaration should have its own symbol table?

Comment: I use a 'stack' of symbol tables that can be traversed, with the TOS being the current lexical scope.

Comment: @FrankC., Can you show tos and ast for my piece of code please?